# Rewriting URLs in discovery page (.well-known/openid-configuration)

Tags: identityserver4

I have IdentityServer4 running behind a load balancer that redirects https calls to http resources.  This means that my IdentityServer will be running on http but will need to show https URLs in it's discovery page (.well-known/openid-configuration).

What's the most elegant way to transform http urls on this page to https?

Comment: a good place to start might be on Dominick Baier's blog: https://leastprivilege.com/2017/10/09/new-in-identityserver4-v2-simplified-configuration-behind-load-balancers-or-reverse-proxies/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `PublicOrigin` option (see [docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/reference/options.html)).

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer( options => 
    options.PublicOrigin = "https://foo.bar.com" 
)
    .AddSigningCredential(...)
    .AddValidationKey(...)
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(...)
    .AddInMemoryClients(...)
    .AddProfileService<...>();
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually ended up being what I did.  Came here to post and you beat me to it.

Comment: I just upgraded IdentityServer4 from 3.1 to 4.1. PublicOrigin is missing. And I still have the same problem, could you clarify how to fix it now?

Comment: Is there a way to do this conditionally, based on the request? Certain requests post HTTP URLs, others post HTTPS URLs. I need HTTP URLs when contacted from inside a k8s cluster, but HTTPS when contacted from the outside.